# How to update multiple values in nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am totally new to MongoDB. I have profiles document and each profile contains languages document.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d23134bbd43c3208034f86f"), 
    "name" : "name1", 
    "languages" : 
        [ 
            { 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d26321e920fba2c147dec73"), 
                "language" : "English", 
                "proficiency" : "elem" 
            }, 
            { 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d2632a5920fba2c147dec74"), 
                "language" : "Italian", 
                "proficiency" : "prof" 
            }
        ], 
    "status" : "ACTIVE"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d231352bd43c3208034f870"), 
    "name" : "name2", 
    "languages" : 
        [ 
            { 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d26321e920fba2c147dec75"), 
                "language" : "Russian", 
                "proficiency" : "elem" 
            }, 
            { 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d2632a5920fba2c147dec76"), 
                "language" : "Ukranian", 
                "proficiency" : "inter" 
            }
        ], 
    "status" : "ARCHIVED"
}
```

I would like to update all proficiencies in the profiles document (elem -> elementary, inter -> intermediate, prof -> proficient). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$ positional filtered operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.col.updateMany({}, 
    { 
        $set: { 
            "languages.$[elem].proficiency": "elementary",
            "languages.$[inter].proficiency": "intermediate",
            "languages.$[prof].proficiency": "proficient",
        } 
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { "elem.proficiency": "elem" },
            { "inter.proficiency": "inter" },
            { "prof.proficiency": "prof" },
        ]
    })
```